# T-SQL stored procedure error

Tags: t-sql

I get the following error when I execute SP in SQL Server 2008 Management Studio:

```
Msg 208, Level 16, State 6, Procedure BackupDB, Line 36

Invalid object name 'dbo.BackupDB'.

use [Master];
go
alter procedure dbo.BackupDB
    @dbName varchar(128),
    @path varchar(256)
as
begin
    declare @device1 varchar(256);
    declare @device2 varchar(256);
    declare @path1 varchar(256);
    declare @path2 varchar(256);
    declare @sql varchar(500);
    if @dbName is null or @path is null
        raiserror('Error: Database name and/or Path missing', 10, 1);
    if not exists(select * from sys.databases where name = @dbName)
        raiserror('Database %s does not exist', 10, 1, @dbName);
    begin
        set @sql = 'ALTER DATABASE ' + @dbName + '; SET RECOVERY FULL;';
        exec(@sql);
        set @device1 = @dbName + '_Data';
        set @device2 = @dbname + '_Log';
        set @path1 = @path + '\' + @dbname + '_Data.bak';
        set @path2 = @path + '\' + @dbname + '_Log.bak';
        print 'path :' + @path1;
        print 'path :' + @path2;
        exec sp_addumpdevice 'disk', @device1, @path1;
        exec sp_addumpdevice 'disk', @device2, @path2;

        backup database @dbName TO @device1;
        backup log @dbName TO @device2;
    end
end
go
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that you haven't created the procedure. Run it again as CREATE PROCEDURE

Comment: Thanks, it works now. But I had created this SP and it did show up in the explorer in the studio, hen why does it throw this message?

Comment: Probably because you are not running the command in the same database as you are looking at (at at least that's why I get these all the time).

Comment: Also possibly it was not created as dbo. but some_other_schema.

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
alter procedure dbo.BackupDB
```

to:

```
create procedure dbo.BackupDB as
```

Answer (score 0):

The SP needs to be created. The top of the sp could be such as:

use [Master];
go
CREATE procedure dbo.BackupDB
--alter procedure dbo.BackupDB
    @dbName varchar(128),
    @path varchar(256)
as
begin

The Alter line is commented out. Then after your execute the procedure & create it you may comment out the create line & uncomment the alter line such as

use [Master];
go
--CREATE procedure dbo.BackupDB
alter procedure dbo.BackupDB

```
@dbName varchar(128),<br>
@path varchar(256)<br>
```

as
begin

Hope this helps,

Catto